# How to change width of a single tab in a ViewPager android?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

### I would like the first tab to be 24dp and two other to fill the left space evenly. How do I do this?

MainActivity.java

```
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(R.layout.custom_tab);
```

custom_tab.xml

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/tab"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"/>
```

Even if I set the `layout_width` in custom_tab to 24 dp, nothing changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I was browsing the internet looking for the correct answer, I checked the medium source sent by [@mmuccito](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8377575/mmucito) but I didn't find the solution there. Then I noticed the similar stackoverflow question which has the answer to this problem submitted by [@digger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8186422/digger):

> You need to lower the weight of the LinearLayout of the corresponding
>   tab.
>
> ```
> LinearLayout layout = ((LinearLayout) ((LinearLayout) tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(YOUR_TAB_NUMBER));
> LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) layout.getLayoutParams();
> layoutParams.weight = YOUR_WEIGHT; // e.g. 0.5f
> layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
> ```
>
> Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You will neeed a custom TabLayout. here is an example that can help you.
https://medium.com/@elsenovraditya/set-tab-minimum-width-of-scrollable-tablayout-programmatically-8146d6101efe